# Is there any way to get data on multiple conditions using aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I am trying to get request users data of a user using aggregation. I got data with multiple queries but now i want do with aggregation. is this possible to get data? can anyone help me?

This is the db structure:

```
{
    "userId": ObjectId("5c5d8a0da8625b038ef016e7"),
    "email": "kishore.bezawada@merritos.com",
    "firstName": "Kishore",
    "lastName": "Bezawada",
    "phoneNumber": "87678356",
    "summary": "",
    "street": "",
    "city": "",
    "state": "",
    "country": "",
    "pinCode": "",
    "requestIds": [
      ObjectId("5c5eaecc3a82593d2d9b7544"), 
      ObjectId("5c5ec25ef3c4aa40de6c9e9b"), 
      ObjectId("5c5e592cc027fa0c8bb9da05"), 
      ObjectId("5c64111a3a4ed22084b2ed6b"), 
      ObjectId("5c5d8a14a8625b038ef016e9"), 
      ObjectId("5c6409e8e9b8ea69f96ceaf3")
    ]
}
```

I done with below:

```
db.profile.find({userId: ObjectId("5c5d8a0da8625b038ef016e7") }, {}).toArray(function(err, info){ db.profile.find({userId: {$in: info[0].requestIds}}, {}).toArray(function(err, resp){console.log(resp)
});
});
```

Now how can I modify this into aggregation?

Comment: it is not clear what you want to get.

Comment: Thanks @felipsmartins to gave reply, Actually i want to get all request users data of a particular user using aggregation

Answer (score 1):

Based on queries in your question here is your solution:

```
db.profile.aggregate([
  { $match: { userId: ObjectId("5c5d8a0da8625b038ef016e7") } },
  { $lookup: { 
    from: 'profile',
    localField: 'requestIds',
    foreignField: 'userId',
    as: 'requests' } 
  }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Arun, but requestIds is an array not a single value, then how can it compare with foreignField

Comment: @SivaMandapati This query will work on the array of objectIds.
In case requestIds is array of object you'll have to unwind the array.